# Windows Explorer is sluggish on host computer while running VMware Workstation

Tags: windows-8, ssd, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I've noticed that while running VMware Fusion (9.0.2) Windows Explorer on the host PC seems sluggish at times. When I attempt to navigate through the directory structure of the SSD that contains the VM image I am currently running, the files and folders appear slowly. This seems to happen unpredictably and is apparently not related to the workload of the running VM (it's happened while the VM is idle and has not happened while under load).

I have two Crucial M4 128 GB SSDs (one with Windows, the other with VM image data). My SWAP is located on the second SSD with the VM data and is 7.68 GB in size (recommended size by Windows). Given that I have 32GB of RAM and the maximum memory size of a VM is 8GB, I doubt I'm hitting the SWAP file, but I'm not sure if it plays a role in my performance issue. Currently my second SSD has 53 of 119 GB free.

Both SSDs are reporting "good" status via S.M.A.R.T., and I'm not running any other disk-intensive applications on the host OS.

I saw this issue today running a VM with Windows 8.1 preview (1 processor, 8GB RAM, 60GB max size, 16GB in use).

I don't even know where to start with trying to figure this out. Any thoughts?

Here's my system specs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried WMWare Player ? 
By my opinion works better !